# My Post form is not reaching the action method inside my asp.net mvc core web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am working on an asp.net MVC core web application, and i have the following routing rules:-

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "IP",
                    pattern: "IP/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "Info",
                    pattern: "Info/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
```

then inside my create form i define the following to use different url when posting back the form depending on the current url:-

```
<form method="post" action="@(!Context.Request.Path.Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains("/info") ? "/IP/submissions/create/": "/info/submissions/create/")" >
```

and here is my post action method:-

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Submission,SubmissionQuestionSubmission")] SubmissionCreate sc )
        {
```

but currently when i post back the form the action method will not be called... any idea? and the browser console will raise this error:-

```
HTTP400: BAD REQUEST - The request could not be processed by the server due to invalid syntax.
POST - https://localhost:44363/info/Submissions/Create/
```

Comment: Are you re-using the same form tag between pages? Normally you'd specify the `asp-controller` `asp-action` and let the framework format the url based on your routes.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman if i use the `asp-controller` & `asp-action` it will refer to the first route rule -the IP in our case-, so it will not use the current routing

Comment: In your case you probably need a route parameter `pattern: "{name}/{controller=Home} ...`, then bind and pass through to your view and add `asp-route-name="@Model.name"`. Or a "named route" `asp-route="IP"`.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman can you advice more on this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-3.1#the-form-tag-helper

Comment: You should ensure that your controller actions map to a single route. Probably by adding a route parameter. Your controller and view should not need to know anything about the mapping between actions and urls.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman now i comment the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` and the post action method was called successfully.. so not sure how i can build the verification token?

Answer (score 0):

It's a "Bad Request" because you aren't using the [form tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-3.1#the-form-tag-helper). Which should build the action url for you and add an anti forgery token.

However, your routes and controller actions should have a 1-1 mapping. Right now you have 3 different routes to the same actions. How are those actions supposed to know which route was used and therefore what action to take? Are you planning on checking the raw url in each action?

Are you attempting to split your controllers into [areas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-3.1)? In which case adding the `asp-controller`, `asp-action`, `asp-route-...` attributes will cause the form tag helper to build the right url for you.

Or would you prefer to add an extra argument to each action, indicating which url was used. Which you could then add to your model so your view can provide it as a route parameter.